# How to modify numercial values in a column of mixed data types in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe in python that looks like this (my actual dataframe is MUCH bigger than this):

```
  col_1 col_2
0   0.8   0.1
1  nope   0.6
2   0.4   0.7
3  nope  nope
```

How can I perform some operations on the numerical values of specific columns. For example, multiply the numerical values of col_2 by 10 to get something like this:

```
  col_1 col_2
0   0.8   1
1  nope   6
2   0.4   7
3  nope  nope
```

Although it looks like a simple task I couldn't find a solution for it anywhere on internet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For a mixed type column, you don't have many choices but loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to convert the `object` type columns to `numeric` columns by using [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html):

```
In [141]: df.col_2 = pd.to_numeric(df.col_2, errors='coerce')
```

`errors='coerce'` converts all non-numeric type values in the column to `NaN`.

Then, multiply by 10:

```
In [144]: df.col_2 = df.col_2 * 10

In [145]: df
Out[145]: 
  col_1  col_2
0   0.8    1.0
1  nope    6.0
2   0.4    7.0
3  nope    NaN
```

if you want to convert `NaN` back to `nope`, you can use [`df.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
In [177]: df.fillna('nope', inplace=True)

In [178]: df
Out[178]: 
  col_1 col_2
0   0.8     1
1  nope     6
2   0.4     7
3  nope  nope
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It worked well for my purpose. Just out of my curiosity, what if there were different string values in such a column? This method wouldn't handle such a case very well.

Comment: All the string values will be converted to `NaN` first. Then the multiplication will happen. Yes, but when you'll try convert the `Nan` back to actual strings, that will be tough. This is a trade-off when you have mixed type columns.

Answer (score 1):

To multiply your column by 10 and preserve your non-numeric values `"nope"` you'll need to convert your column to a numeric dtype and replace the non-numeric values with `NaN`. Then you'll perform your operation on that column and replace only the values in that column that were numeric to begin with, leaving the non-numeric values in place.

```
numeric_col2 = pd.to_numeric(df["col_2"], errors="coerce")
df.loc[numeric_col2.notnull(), "col_2"] = numeric_col2 * 10

print(df)
  col_1 col_2
0   0.8     1
1  nope     6
2   0.4     7
3  nope  nope
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. This works equally well as @Mayank's answer.